# Who signs the system apps?

Tags: system-apps

Who signs the system apps? Google, or is it the OEM when they build the ROM? Also, has this changed over the years?

Comment: System apps are signed with the same key the ROM has been signed, so on stock devices it is usually the manufacturer. As far as I remember this has not changed in the history of Android.

Comment: Dang, there goes that writing idea I _totally_ didn't have. Thank you though!